# Distribute rows to individual sheets based on cell value vs sheet name

Tags: excel, vba

I have this vba code that appends/distributes records from a Data mastersheet to individual named sheets. This is done based on column E's value. It works fine but ends in an error whenever it encounters a value on column E that's not one of the sheets in the file. Can you please help me so as to allow it to just skip those records and proceed with the processing? Thanks!

```
Sub CopyDataToSheets()


Dim copyfromws As Worksheet
Dim copytows As Worksheet
Dim cfrng As Range
Dim ctrng As Range
Dim cflr As Long
Dim ctlr As Long
Dim i As Long
Dim currval As String


Set copyfromws = Sheets("Data")
cflr = copyfromws.Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row

'   Copy Row of Data to Specific Worksheet based on value in Column E
'   Existing Formulas in Columns F through H or J are automatically extended to the new row of data
For i = 2 To cflr
    currval = copyfromws.Cells(i, 1).Value
    Set copytows = Sheets(currval)
    ctlr = copytows.Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row + 1
    Set cfrng = copyfromws.Range("A" & i & ":N" & i)
    Set ctrng = copytows.Range("A" & ctlr & ":N" & ctlr)
    ctrng.Value = cfrng.Value
Next


End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I would make a small helper function that can test if the worksheet exists. That way you can control the logic of your loop.

```vb
Function SheetExists(sheetName As String, Optional wb As Workbook) As Boolean
    If wb Is Nothing Then Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    
    On Error Resume Next
    Set ws = wb.Sheets(sheetName)
    SheetExists = Err = 0
End Function
```